# SharedPreferances are giving null values in next activity

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I am trying to send  data from the activity to the BroadcastReceiver class and then again from receiver class to service class.For the first time data goes properly but after that it gives nullPointer exception

here is my activity code:-

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent i=new Intent();
                            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, Myreceiver.class);
                            i.putExtra("name",et.getText().toString().trim());
                            sendBroadcast(i);
                            et.setText("");

                    }
```

In Myreceiver class

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String data=intent.getExtras().getString("name");
    SharedPreferences sp=context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();

    Intent i=new Intent(context,MyService.class);
    if (!data.equals("") && !data.isEmpty())
    {
        editor.putString("data",data).commit();
        i.putExtra("names",data);
        Log.e("Myreceiver data is ",data);

    }
    else {
        String name = sp.getString("data", "");
        i.putExtra("names",name);
        Log.e("Myreceiver data is not",name);
    }

        context.startService(i);




}
```

In my service class

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     name=intent.getExtras().getString("names");\\Line 40
     Log.e("MyService class",name);
```

For second time it gives null pointer at above line usually when activity's receiver is in background

error log:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.evoqis.trnode.MyService.onStartCommand(MyService.java:40)
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Where exactly do you get the null pointer?

Comment: @naveen in service class where I am getting name using intent. Getextras()

Comment: @mitesh.. I have used. Comit()

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion` ? and post you error log.

Comment: error log posted

Comment: Somehow, you intent is going `null`. How come? Is your service `START_STICKY`? What is device's Android version?

Comment: my service is not START_STICKY.. device version Android 5.1

Comment: Are you getting the name value in onReceive()?

Comment: yes i am getting value in onReceive as well as in onStartCommand

Comment: add this `editor.apply(); `below   SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();

Comment: used editor.apply but not worked :/

Answer (score 0):

On handleIntent and onStartCommand use this code for get intent.

```
protected void onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    data=(String) intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
}
```

Comment: but already there is object of intent..So getIntent() is not available in that method please see my code.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving data as bundle,

```
intent.getExtras().getString("name"); //using getExtras() receives bundle
```

But you are sending data without bundle,

```
i.putExtra("name",et.getText().toString().trim());
```

Put extras instead of extra. Like-

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", et.getText().toString().trim());
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getExtras() change to getStringExtra().

**MyReceiver Class**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
 String data=intent.getStringExtra("name");
 ...
}
```

**MyService Class**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
 name=intent.getStringExtra("names");
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your responses but i found a very easy solution for my problem.Which may help someone in future.
Here is my Main Activity code:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Myreceiver.class);
                            SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("data",et.getText().toString()).commit();
                            editor.apply();
                            sendBroadcast(i);
                            et.setText("");
```

And in Service class

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String string = prefs.getString("data","");
```

This will work even if the application is closed...
Thanks:)